# How to install OpenSSH on stripped down Linux OS without a package manager

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, source

I have a satellite box that uses a stripped down version of linux OS. It runs enigma2 SVN-2860 based on GIT-5580 used for watching satellite and terrestrial digital tv. It's a PKT Hyperion enigma2 image.

Some more details about the box:

```
spark7162:~# uname -a
Linux spark7162 2.6.32.59_stm24_0211 #1 PREEMPT Wed Feb 26 23:10:39 CET 2014 sh4 GNU/Linux

spark7162:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo
machine         : hdk7105
processor       : 0
cpu family      : sh4
cpu variant     : st40-300
cpu type        : STx7105
cut             : 4.x
cpu flags       : fpu icbi synco fpchg
cache type      : split (harvard)
icache size     : 32KiB (2-way)
dcache size     : 32KiB (2-way)
address sizes   : 32 bits physical
bogomips        : 538.62
```

It doesn't have an ssh server or client. It has Samba, Telnet and vsftp.

I would like to use rsync to copy files (TV recordings) off a usb key connected to this satellite box. I really want to use rsync so I can preserve the timestamps of the recordings.

From my reading it won't be possible to rsync because this box doesn't have an ssh server. I also read that you could use rsync with rsh instead of ssh but for that I would also need to install rsh on the satellite box.

Furthermore I don't think this box even has a package manager like dpkg or anything like that.

**My Question:**
Is it possible to download the installation files for OpenSSH server/client and install them manually on this box? Maybe there will be too many unmet dependencies and incompatibilities and it's just not worth the hassle?

Cheers,

Flex

Comment: See [Beyond LSF - Open SSH](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/openssh.html).

Comment: Cheers for that. I can telnet to the command line of the satellite receivers Linux OS. There is an "install" command but no option to give the -v (verbose) flag.. maybe that is not a show stopper. The box has no groupadd or useradd utilities which according to your linked page are needed to install OpenSSH. Do you know if there is another way to set up those user and groups for the sshd daemon?

Comment: This system doesn't seem to have a "make" command either.. maybe it won't be possible to install OpenSSH on it at all?

Comment: Maybe you can cross-compile on some other system and just copy the built files there?